# How to make a mapping to scroll splits together for only one line at a time?

Tags: key-bindings, scrolling

I know about `:scrollbind`, but I only want to move the splits together one line at a time. I think what I have tried explains what I am trying to do, although it doesn't work:

```
" Scroll splits together one line
nnoremap <C-S-e> :set scrollbind <C-e> :set noscrollbind
nnoremap <C-S-y> :set scrollbind <C-y> :set noscrollbind
```

Comment: `:set scrollbind` only affects the current window. You need to `scrollbind` the other splits as well. Also, remember to add a `<CR>` at the end of each `:` command

Comment: @husB: Thanks, but I tried this and it's still not working: `nnoremap <C-S-e> :set scrollbind<CR> <C-w><C-w><C-e> :set noscrollbind<CR>`

Comment: Is the other window 'scrollbind'-ed? Do a `:set scrolllbind<CR>` after `<C-w><C-w>`. (One needs to `:set scrollbind` in each split window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all windows set scrollbind, execute `<C-e>` (or `<C-y>`), for all windows unset scrollbind.

```
nnoremap <C-e> :windo set scb<CR><C-e>:windo set noscb<CR>
nnoremap <C-y> :windo set scb<CR><C-y>:windo set noscb<CR>
```

[image]

Comment: That works, although I cannot map them to `<C-S-e>` and `<C-S-y>` for some reason.

Comment: vim can't map anything to `CTRL+SHIFT+letter` afaik